# Catch ClaimsIssuer on asp.net core 2 ConfigureServices

Tags: asp.net, jwt, token, asp.net-core-webapi

I am looking a way to grab the value of Claim Issuer. I want to make 2 way validation of token.
First step user will get the token from System API and pass it to Customer API. In customer API token need to be validate with system API token parameter.

if it is validated customer api generate a new token to the user and user will use the new token in next steps.

I am doing this because in the second step I will add some claim for only that user have to see and use. like connection string, user role for its own database.
Or is there any other way to do like this verification ?

thanks.

```
services.AddAuthentication(options =>
        {
            options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            options.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        })
        .AddJwtBearer(options =>
        {
            if (????)
            {
                // system token validator
            }
            else
            {
                //customer token validator
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Found a way to handle the problem

Just add two claim issuer and two key to validation parameter so I don't need to check anymore the claim issuer

```
var issuers = new List<string>()
                            {
                                Configuration["SystemToken:Issuer"],
                                Configuration["CustomerToken:Issuer"]
                            };
                SecurityKey SystemKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Configuration["SystemToken:Key"]));
                SecurityKey CustomerKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Configuration["CustomerToken:Key"]));
                options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters()
                {
                    ValidateIssuer = true,
                    ValidIssuers = issuers,
                    ValidateAudience = false,
                    ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                    IssuerSigningKeys = new List<SecurityKey>() { SystemKey, CustomerKey },
                    ValidateLifetime = true
                };
```

thanks you for helping 
@Tratcher
https://github.com/aspnet/Security/issues/1604